# Formatting Excel data into smaller pivot tables

Tags: python, performance, excel, pandas

The code below (`Distribution.py`) reads the results I get from a simulation I am running and formats them into smaller pivot tables. The data comes out as excel files with several worksheets. With smaller data files it is fast but quite slow processing larger data files. Any hints on how I can improve how I can improve its speed of operation?

The sample data below is named Distribution1, it is a worksheet in the excel file sample.xlsx

### Distribution.py

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter

def distribution_data_processor(luti_data_file, sheetname):

    """A function that analysis LUTI model trip distribution results and return pivot

         tables of given scenarios or variable combinations"""

    # Define variables
    temp = []
    list_dfs = []
    final_dfs_list = []

    # Read excel input file and create a map of of all worksheets in Pandas
    df_map = pd.read_excel(luti_data_file, sheetname=None)

    # Make a pandas data frame of a given worksheet
    d = df_map[sheetname]

    # Delete the Variable column since its values are redundant
    del d['Variable']

    # Get unique values of each column in the data frame
    num_pur = d['Purpose'].unique()
    num_time = d['Time Period'].unique()
    num_mode = d['Mode'].unique()

    # Create sub pivot tables from the data
    for time in num_time:

        try:
            tp = d[d['Time Period'] == time]

            for pur in num_pur:

                pivoted = tp.loc[tp['Purpose'] == pur].pivot_table(index=['Zone (origin)', 'Time Period',
                       'Purpose', 'Mode'], columns=['Zone (destination)'], values=['1995-Jan-01 00:00:00',
                           '2000-Jan-01 00:00:00', '2005-Jan-01 00:00:00']).fillna(0.0)

                list_dfs.append(pivoted)

        except IndexError: pass

    # Analyse further the tables with two values in the mode column
    for df in list_dfs:
        mask = df.index.get_level_values(3) == 'Bus'

        df1 = df[mask]
        temp.append(df1)

        df2 = df[~mask]
        temp.append(df2)

    # Eliminate redundant or empty pivot
    final_dfs_list = [i for idx, i in enumerate(temp) if i.index.values.any()]

    return final_dfs_list


def save_xls(list_dfs, xls_path):

    """ A function to write the results of the distribution

        processor function above to file """

    writer = ExcelWriter(xls_path)
    for n, df in enumerate(list_dfs):
        df.to_excel(writer, 'sheet%s' % n)
    writer.save()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #distribution_data_processor('sample.xlsx', 'Distribution1')
    save_xls(distribution_data_processor('sample.xlsx', 'Distribution1'), 'result.xlsx')
```

### Distribution1

Formatted for better readability:

```
Variable  Time Period  Purpose              Mode         Zone (origin)      Zone (destination)  1995-Jan-01 00:00:00  2000-Jan-01 00:00:00  2005-Jan-01 00:00:00
Trips     Rest_of_day  Home_Others_Car      Bus          Zonnebloem         Heathfield          0.001                 3.19544E-07           0.004420692
Trips     Rest_of_day  Home_Others_Car      Bus          Zonnebloem         Heideveld           0.001                 1.49769E-10           1.88921E-06
Trips     Rest_of_day  Home_Others_Car      Bus          Zonnebloem         Helderberg Rural    0.001                 3.072E-08             0.00012523
Trips     Rest_of_day  Home_Others_Car      Bus          Zonnebloem         Hout Bay            0.001                 4.36081E-07           0.010432741
Trips     Rest_of_day  Home_Others_Car      Bus          Zonnebloem         Joostenberg Vlakte  0.001                 2.81437E-08           0.00014551
Trips     Rest_of_day  Home_Others_Car      Bus          Zonnebloem         Kenilworth          0.001                 8.54678E-06           0.082402039
Trips     Rest_of_day  Home_Others_Minibus  Car+Minibus  Airport Industria  Dunoon              0.001                 3.9958E-07            3.80314E-07
Trips     Rest_of_day  Home_Others_Minibus  Car+Minibus  Airport Industria  Durbanville         0.001                 1.43952E-05           1.98133E-05
Trips     Rest_of_day  Home_Others_Minibus  Car+Minibus  Airport Industria  Edgemead            0.001                 5.70312E-07           7.6349E-07
Trips     Rest_of_day  Home_Others_Minibus  Car+Minibus  Airport Industria  Eersterivier        0.014476378           1.53594E-06           1.58987E-06
Trips     Rest_of_day  Home_Others_Minibus  Car+Minibus  Airport Industria  Elsies River        0.052003373           5.33659E-06           3.71889E-06
Trips     Rest_of_day  Home_Others_Minibus  Car+Minibus  Airport Industria  Epping Industria    0.090892934           9.43124E-11           6.70574E-11
```

Comment: Honestly, `pd.read_excel` is historically pretty slow and probably your biggest bottle neck.  [Is it possible to convert to csv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766133/faster-way-to-read-excel-files-to-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @Tony converting to csv is really not an option because of the file sizes and the number of worksheets in the excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright well if converting to a csv isn't possible, there's some improvements we can make, but `pd.read_excel` will probably always be your bottle neck.  Regardless here's some small fixes that might help:

First, which will make more sense after the other parts, but most importantly maybe i'm missing something with your main function... you just pass in one worksheet name, yet you load the entire workbook?  *See NOTE:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter

def distribution_data_processor(luti_data_file, sheetname):
    """A function that analysis LUTI model trip distribution results and return pivot
       tables of given scenarios or variable combinations"""

    # # you won't need to initialize any lists because we're just yielding `pd.DataFrames`
    # # Define variables
    # temp = []
    # list_dfs = []
    # final_dfs_list = []

    # *NOTE:  This might actually be why performance is so bad
    # if you're going to load into pandas the workbook, and then cut out a worksheet,
    # why not just only load the worksheet?

    # Read excel input file and create a map of of all worksheets in Pandas
    df_map = pd.read_excel(luti_data_file, sheetname=sheetname)

    # # Make a pandas data frame of a given worksheet
    # d = df_map[sheetname]

    # Delete the Variable column since its values are redundant
    # df.drop(<column name>, <0/1>) #0 for row, 1 for column
    d = d.drop('Variable', 1)
```

Second, converting `set(df[col])` will be faster than `df.unique()`:

```
    # tested on df.shape()==(10, 10000000) with df["a"]==random.choice(list("abc"))
    %timeit -n 25 df["a"].unique() # 221 ms ± 2.93 ms per loop
    %timeit -n 25 set(df["a"])     # 171 ms ± 1.2 ms per loop

    # In your code just remove these unique statements, and put them in the for loop
    # NOTE: you won't find num_mode here because I didn't see it used anywhere
```

Third, might as well combine the two `for` loops:

```
    # Create sub pivot tables from the data
    for time in set(d(["Time Period"]):
        try:
            # No time diffs between d[bool] and d.loc[bool]
            # it's just nice to stay consistent
            tp = d.loc[d['Time Period'] == time]

            for pur in set(d["Purpose"]):
                # Note it's common in big pandas commands to wrap them in ()
                # so that you don't need to use multi-line seperator \
                # and then line everything up for readability
                pivoted = (tp.loc[tp['Purpose'] == pur]
                             .pivot_table(index=['Zone (origin)', 'Time Period', 'Purpose', 'Mode'], 
                                          columns=['Zone (destination)'], 
                                          values=['1995-Jan-01 00:00:00', '2000-Jan-01 00:00:00', '2005-Jan-01 00:00:00'])
                             .fillna(0.0))

                # ... mask loop below ...
```

And lastly, by restructuring this into a generator you might see some performance boost:

```
                # you can also just test for empty index rather than enumerate
                # without your data i'm not sure this might be bad because 
                # the try could of already broke here?
                if (pivoted.index.any()):
                    yield None, None

                mask = pivoted.index.get_level_values(3) == "Bus"
                mask_true = pivoted[mask]
                mask_false = pivoted[~mask]

                yield mask_true, mask_false

        except IndexError:
            yield None, None
```

With a little parameter tweaking turning this into a generator shouldn't be to hard.  You'll want to test against `None` though as it's a possibility for the error catching and empty pivots.

```
def save_xls(generator, input_file, worksheet, xls_path):

    """ A function to write the results of the distribution

        processor function above to file """

    writer = ExcelWriter(xls_path)
    increment = 0
    for mask_true, mask_false in generator(input_file, worksheet):
        if mask_true is not None and mask_false is not None:
            mask_true.to_excel(writer, 'sheet%s' & increment)
            increment += 1
            mask_false.to_excel(writer, 'sheet%s' % increment)
            increment += 1
    writer.save()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #distribution_data_processor('sample.xlsx', 'Distribution1')
    save_xls(distribution_data_processor, 'sample.xlsx', 'Distribution1', 'result.xlsx')
```

Comment: I edited the last bit a bunch, I took a break and got some food.  Now i'm skeptical of this solution.  I'm thinking a groupby could of possibly worked just as well...